# What does ffserver's AVOptionVideo cpu-used option do?

Tags: ffmpeg

I can't find this anywhere, but most ffserver config files I see have it included - what does this do:

```
AVOptionVideo cpu-used 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an option for [the `libvpx` encoder](http://www.webmproject.org/code/) (Google's WebM encoder). It's a codec-specific option and not used in any other encoders as far as I know of.

`-cpu-used 0` seems like a good default, so maybe that's why people include it in their configurations.

`-cpu-used` can only be used when the `-quality` option is set. You can therefore use it with `-quality good` or `-quality rt`. For a list of options, run `ffmpeg -h full` and look at the `libvpx` section.

Here's how to set the values.

#### With `-quality good`:

The `-cpu-used` values range from 0 to 5. This sets the behavior of the encoder with respect to speed.

From [the VP8 docs](http://www.webmproject.org/docs/encoder-parameters/):

> Setting `--cpu-used=1` or `--cpu-used=2` will give further significant boosts to encode speed, but will start to have a more noticeable impact on quality and may also start to effect the accuracy of the data rate control.
>
> Setting a value of 4 or 5 will turn off “rate distortion optimisation” which has a big impact on quality, but also greatly speeds up the encoder.

Disabling rate distortion optimization would really impact the quality, so you shouldn't set this unless absolutely necessary.

#### With `-quality rt`:

In this mode, the CPU/quality tradeoff is chosen by  the encoder. The CPU usage is calculated as:

> target cpu utilisation = (100*(16-cpu-used)/16)%

You can set `-cpu-used` from 0–15 here.